# How to change multiple Labels based on Combobox selection?

Tags: combobox, tkinter

I would like yo know how to have multiple values in different labels depending on a `Combobox` drop down  list selection. For instance,  suppose you have one `Combobox` with the values (`car`, `house`, `computer`) and multiple `Label`s which reflect different sizes and colors when selecting `Combobox`. If I select `car`, I will have for size: `big`, color: `black`  and so on...

Answer (score 6):

The Combobox widget generates the virtual event `<<ComboboxSelected>>`, which you can use to change the options of the labels according to the current value:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

values = ['car', 'house', 'computer']
root = tk.Tk()
labels = dict((value, tk.Label(root, text=value)) for value in values)

def handler(event):
    current = combobox.current()
    if current != -1:
        for label in labels.values():
            label.config(relief='flat')
        value = values[current]
        label = labels[value]
        label.config(relief='raised')

combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=values)
combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', handler)
combobox.pack()
for value in labels:
    labels[value].pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dear @A.Rodas, thank you very much for your prompt response. Actually there was a misunderstanding since what I want to do is quite far different from your answer. It was my fault since my explanation was not very clear.
What I ment was a combobox with different values to select, for example:

Combobox A ---> Values: Car, House, Computer

Entries ---> 3 Entries.

Labels for entries --> Size, Color, Price.

If I select Car from Combobox A, what I will see in entries is as follows:

Entry One for Size: Big 
Entry Two for Color: Blue
Entry Three for Price: Excessive.

Thank you very much indeed

Comment: @hector: you can use this answer to solve your problem. Just replace the code in the handler with whatever you need to do. You can add or remove widgets, reconfigure widgets, change labels, etc. this answer shows how to call a function and get the value of the combobox when the user changes the value.

Comment: Hector: I've done what @Bryan suggested, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16968766/355230) to your follow-up question. Note, this comment is mainly for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a textvariable attribute to a combobox, then put a trace on that variable. The trace will cause a function to be called whenever the value of the combobox changes. In this function you can then set the text for any labels you want.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what exactly do you mean by "put a trace on that variable"?

Comment: @margineau: You can attach an observer to the variable -- a function that gets called whenever the variable is set, unset, or read. You do this via the `trace` method on a `StringVar`,  `IntVar`, `DoubleVar` and `BooleanVar`.