# How to change multiple Entry widgets based on Combobox selection?

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter

Yesterday I had a problem with a `Combobox` selection which can be seen at the following link:

[How to change multiple Labels based on Combobox selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925920/how-to-change-multiple-labels-based-on-combobox-selection)

Unfortunately I was not be able to express my idea, so my problem was not be solved. Anyway, thanks for your kind help. What I really mean is better expressed by the following code, the problem is that it is using a `Listbox` instead a `Combobox`.

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.minsize(500,300)
root.maxsize(550,310)

class MyListbox:
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title(title)
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.Closes)

        self.myData= (
            ["1", "Jhon Doe", "Madrid", "0341-672541", "6 SD"],
            ["2", "Mike Grant", "Barcelona", "0341-435271", "6 SD"],
            ["3", "Steven Mc Fly", "Rome", "0341-123456", "6 SD"],
            ["4", "Joao Pontes", "Rio", "0341-234567", "6 SD"],
            ["5", "Kenji S.", "Tokyo", "0341-213212", "6 SD"])

        self.stablishment()
        self.SeT()
        self.Listbox_Content()
        self.Data_Content()

        self.listboxData.focus_set()

    def SeT(self):
        self.listboxData.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.click)
        self.listboxData.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.click)

    def click(self, event=None):
        self.Data_Content()

    def Data_Content(self):
        index = self.listboxData.curselection()
        code = int(index[0])

        self.entNumber.delete(0, END)
        self.entName.delete(0, END)
        self.entCity.delete(0, END)
        self.entTel.delete(0, END)
        self.entAddress.delete(0, END)

        self.entNumber.insert(END, self.myData[code][0])
        self.entName.insert(END, self.myData[code][1])
        self.entCity.insert(END, self.myData[code][2])
        self.entTel.insert(END, self.myData[code][3])
        self.entAddress.insert(END, self.myData[code][4])

    def Listbox_Content(self):
        for dat in range(len(self.myData)):
            self.listboxData.insert(END, self.myData[dat][1])

        self.listboxData.selection_set(0)

    def stablishment(self):
        mainFrame = Frame(self.parent)
        mainFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.statusBar = Label(mainFrame, text="App",relief=SUNKEN, bd=1)
        self.statusBar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        fr_left = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10)
        fr_left.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=LEFT)

        scroll = Scrollbar(fr_left, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.listboxData = Listbox(fr_left, width=30,yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

        self.listboxData.pack(fill=Y, side=LEFT)
        scroll.configure(command=self.listboxData.yview)
        scroll.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        fr_right = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10)
        fr_right.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=RIGHT)

        fr_up = Frame(fr_right)
        fr_up.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)

        Label(fr_up, text='List Number').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entNumber = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entNumber.grid(row=0, column=1)

        Label(fr_up, text='Name').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entName = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entName.grid(row=1, column=1)

        Label(fr_up, text='City').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entCity = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entCity.grid(row=2, column=1)

        Label(fr_up, text='No. Tel').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entTel = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entTel.grid(row=3, column=1)

        Label(fr_up, text='Address').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entAddress = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entAddress.grid(row=4, column=1)

    def Closes(self, event=None):
        self.parent.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyListbox(root, "Main Window") 
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code in the A. Rodas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926422/355230) to your earlier question adapted (more-or-less) to the idea expressed in code you posted with this question:

```
try:  # Python 3
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *  # Python 2
    import ttk


root = Tk()
root.minsize(500,300)
root.maxsize(550,310)

class MyListbox:
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title(title)
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closes)

        self.myData= (
            ["1", "Jhon Doe", "Madrid", "0341-672541", "6 SD"],
            ["2", "Mike Grant", "Barcelona", "0341-435271", "7 SD"],
            ["3", "Steven Mc Fly", "Rome", "0341-123456", "8 SD"],
            ["4", "Joao Pontes", "Rio", "0341-234567", "9 SD"],
            ["5", "Kenji S.", "Tokyo", "0341-213212", "10 SD"])

        self.establishment()

    def combobox_handler(self, event):
        current = self.combobox.current()
        self.entNumber.delete(0, END)
        self.entName.delete(0, END)
        self.entCity.delete(0, END)
        self.entTel.delete(0, END)
        self.entAddress.delete(0, END)

        self.entNumber.insert(END, self.myData[current][0])
        self.entName.insert(END, self.myData[current][1])
        self.entCity.insert(END, self.myData[current][2])
        self.entTel.insert(END, self.myData[current][3])
        self.entAddress.insert(END, self.myData[current][4])

    def establishment(self):
        mainFrame = Frame(self.parent)
        mainFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.statusBar = Label(mainFrame, text="App",relief=SUNKEN, bd=1)
        self.statusBar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        fr_left = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10)
        fr_left.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=LEFT)

        names = [person[1] for person in self.myData]
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(fr_left, values=names)
        self.combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.combobox_handler)
        self.combobox.pack()

        fr_right = Frame(mainFrame, bd=10)
        fr_right.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES, side=RIGHT)

        fr_up = Frame(fr_right)
        fr_up.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)

        Label(fr_up, text='List Number').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entNumber = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entNumber.grid(row=0, column=1)

        Label(fr_up, text='Name').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entName = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entName.grid(row=1, column=1)

        Label(fr_up, text='City').grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entCity = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entCity.grid(row=2, column=1)

        Label(fr_up, text='No. Tel').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entTel = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entTel.grid(row=3, column=1)

        Label(fr_up, text='Address').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.entAddress = Entry(fr_up)
        self.entAddress.grid(row=4, column=1)

    def closes(self, event=None):
        self.parent.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyListbox(root, "Main Window")
    root.mainloop()
```